# How can I debug code after I moved it to a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, stack-trace, better-errors-gem

I want to be able to see in the better-error exception page the full stack trace to the method which contains the error.

After I move the helper file to a gem and use this gem in my app, if an error occurs the better-error gem cannot show in the exception page the details inside the gem code and shows the method in my app which calls the first method in the gem.

In this way I cannot easily debug the code inside the gem file.

In general, what is the proposed way in debugging code that exists in a gem (or engine)?

Comment: I think you have the option to display the full stack trace (and not only the application stack trace) which reveals the calls made in the gems

Comment: Dear @MrYoshiji,
You are correct, in better-errors exception page, on the left in the stack trace, there is the option "Application Frames" and "All frames".
I select the "All frames" option and I see the gem inner code.
https://github.com/BetterErrors/better_errors/wiki
Thank you very much for your kind help and time :)
Please add the details as an answer in order to accept it

Comment: You can find great answers to this question in other places already, google "debugging a gem"

Answer (score 1):

As @MrYoshiji suggested,

in better-errors exception page, on the left in the stack trace, there is the option "Application Frames" and "All frames".
If I select the "All frames" option I see the gem inner code.

That was what I was looking for...

github.com/BetterErrors/better_errors/wiki

Dear @MrYoshiji,
Thank you very much for your kind help and time :)